# how to get the response data into array?

Tags: iphone, ios5

hi all how is the code for get the total response in the array actually i have implemented code as shown in the below here my problem is when i calling the method in in next class i am getting array response null so plz help me to avoid this problem in iphone.

My code is:

-(void)countrySelection{

```
    NSString *jobSearchUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://infra2appsmobile.cloudapp.net/Infra2Apps.svc/Countries"];
    //NSLog(@"url for new articles is = %@",jobSearchUrlString);
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:jobSearchUrlString]];   

    NSURLConnection *theconnection =  [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if (theconnection) {
        RoutData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    }

}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{   

    [RoutData setLength: 0];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [RoutData appendData:data];

           NSString *thexml = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:RoutData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSDictionary *dictXML= [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:thexml error:nil];

    NSMutableArray *arrStation = [[dictXML objectForKey:@"feed"] objectForKey:@"entry"] ;//this would return the array of station dictionaries

    for (int i=0; i<[arrStation count]; i++) {
        NSLog(@"---->> String Type Country names <<---: %@",[[[[[arrStation objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"content"] objectForKey:@"m:properties"] objectForKey:@"d:CountryName"] objectForKey:@"text"]);
        [materialarray addObject:[[[[[arrStation objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"content"] objectForKey:@"m:properties"] objectForKey:@"d:CountryName"] objectForKey:@"text"]];

        NSLog(@"--->>** Array Type Country names **<<<---%@",materialarray);


    }



}
```

My response is:

2012-03-09 12:49:40.856 TableSample[4862:f803] ---->> String Type Country names <<---: 
        France
2012-03-09 12:49:40.867 TableSample[4862:f803] --->>** Array Type Country names **<<<---(null)
2012-03-09 12:49:40.868 TableSample[4862:f803] ---->> String Type Country names <<---: 
        MEA HQ
2012-03-09 12:49:40.869 TableSample[4862:f803] --->>** Array Type Country names **<<<---(null)
2012-03-09 12:49:40.870 TableSample[4862:f803] ---->> String Type Country names <<---: 
        Israel 
2012-03-09 12:49:40.871 TableSample[4862:f803] --->>** Array Type Country names **<<<---(null)
2012-03-09 12:49:40.872 TableSample[4862:f803] ---->> String Type Country names <<---: 
        Turkey
2012-03-09 12:49:40.879 TableSample[4862:f803] --->>** Array Type Country names **<<<---(null)
2012-03-09 12:49:40.879 TableSample[4862:f803] ---->> String Type Country names <<---: 
        UAE
2012-03-09 12:49:40.880 TableSample[4862:f803] --->>** Array Type Country names **<<<---(null)
2012-03-09 12:49:40.881 TableSample[4862:f803] ---->> String Type Country names <<---: 
        SA
2012-03-09 12:49:40.881 TableSample[4862:f803] --->>** Array Type Country names **<<<---(null)
2012-03-09 12:49:40.882 TableSample[4862:f803] ---->> String Type Country names <<---: 
        RSA
2012-03-09 12:49:41.020 TableSample[4862:f803] --->>** Array Type Country names **<<<---(null)
2012-03-09 12:49:41.021 TableSample[4862:f803] ---->> String Type Country names <<---: 
        WE HQ
2012-03-09 12:49:41.022 TableSample[4862:f803] --->>** Array Type Country names **<<<---(null

Comment: i know answer but i don't like to give an answer to u !!!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `connectionDidFinishLoading` delegate method you will get the response string, you need to call `JSONValue` on that response string it will give you the results in an array.

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    [connection release];
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"responseString %@",responseString);
    self.responseData = nil;
    NSArray *responseArray = [responseString JSONValue];
    [responseString release];
}
```

Comment: sorry friend it is not working in my application becoz basically it is xml parsing. give me another ans for me

Comment: You are implementing JSON parser delegate methods. If you are using XML parsing you need implement NSXMLParser delegate methods. Here is the link for it: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that `materialarray` is allocated.

I think there is where the problem is.

Hope this helps.